# When does gulp log its tasks?

Tags: logging, build, gulp, stdout, gulp-watch

My current observation is: tasks without dependency tasks will print, e.g:

```
[16:24:32] Starting 'server'...
[16:24:32] Finished 'server' after 20 ms
```

Tasks with dependencies won't produce this output (with my current setup).
Especially tasks triggered by `gulp.watch` work, but won't print start or finished

But I might be completely mistaken, so

1) Where can I find a documentation about these log strings?

2) How to enable printing every start and finished for all tasks?

Comment: Tasks with dependencies do log start and finish.  Though, they won't log them until the dependencies all finish.  So, you might not see them until the end of the log.

Comment: So are you saying: Tasks with dependencies will log their start, but won't log start and finish of the dependencies until all dependencies finish? I don't understand that :D

Comment: No. Tasks are logged in the order in which they are executed.  If a task has dependencies, it won't start until all of those dependencies finish.  So, if you have a task 'build-car' with dependencies ['build-wheels', 'build-engine'].  build-car can't start until build-wheels and build-engine finish. So you may see a log like this "start build-wheels, finish build-wheels, start build-engine, finish build-engine, start build-car, finish build-car".  Though, the dependencies can actually execute in any order and may even execute "simultaneously" (unless, of course, they depend on each other).

Comment: This is pretty fundamental to the way gulp, and almost any automated build system, works.  You might want to go back and read the documentation more closely.